# no mixin named Rtable-cell--light error in Scss

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I have a ionic app that has a page.html which im tryng to apply this sass code to my flexbox table but cant compile. I have this css to style bg color

```
                        .Rtable-cell--light {
                                            background-color: white;
                                            border-color: mix(white,$tableColour,80%);
                                            }
```

Which i call inside my Rtable-cell with include

```
                            .Rtable-cell {
                                    box-sizing: border-box;
                                    flex-grow: 1;
                                    width: 100%;  // Default to full width
                                    padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
                                    overflow: hidden; // Or flex might break
                                    list-style: none;
                                    border: solid $bw white;
                                    background: fade(slategrey,20%);
                                    > h1, > h2, > h3, > h4, > h5, > h6 { margin: 0; }
                                    margin: -$bw 0 0 -$bw;  //border collapse offset
                                    @include Rtable-cell--light;
                                    }
```

Why do i getting the error?

My flexbox table looks like this

```
      <div class="Rtable Rtable--4cols">

        <div class="Rtable-cell"><h3>Eddard Stark</h3></div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Ice</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">No direwolf</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell"><strong>Lord of Winterfell</strong></div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell"><h3>Jon Snow</h3></div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Longclaw</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Direwolf: Ghost</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell"><strong>Knows nothing</strong></div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell"><h3>Arya Stark</h3></div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Needle</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Direwolf: Nymeria</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell"><strong>No one</strong></div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong keyword.
.Rtable-cell--light is not a mixin, but rather a selector, so instead of @include, you should use @extend, like:

```
@extend .Rtable-cell--light;
```

Doc link: http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7

Comment: The docs seems to be pointing into wrong section (# links seems not to be working correct there), but you can just find "extending/inheritance" section. :)

Comment: Even better is to use [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Placeholder_Selectors___foo) to avoid creating separate CSS rule in a case if `Rtable-cell--light` is used only as template.

Comment: Thanks man, you are right. I will read a bit more of the sass doc asap